# javascript interpolation

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var myapp={msg:{vote:{dupe:"this is adupe"}}};   
function alert_msg(msg_code) { alert('myapp.msg.'+msg_code) }
```

where msg_code is `vote.dupe` and returned from server-side. how do I make the `alert_msg` function work?  the only fast solution i can think of is `eval`..

btw, is there better way to organize the error messages in js? I am currently trying to return msg code then substitute it in js.

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking for, are you trying to call the alert_msg function? if so, you just need to call it `alert_msg(myapp.msg.vote.dupe);`

Comment: the param msg_code is dynamic and the server side return a msg code to ajax call which feed to alert_msg(msg_code).. so your solution isn't doable.

Comment: definetly @Phrogz solution is better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alert(myapp.msg[msg_code]);
```

All properties of JavaScript objects can be accessed either through dot notation (e.g. `foo.bar`) or bracket notation (e.g. `foo["bar"]`). The latter is useful (necessary) when your property name is in a variable (as in your case) or when you need to get or set a property that is an invalid identifier, e.g. `foo["text-align"]` or `foo["OM!T Thsi@ is a ∞ prop¢rty?!"] = "yes";`.

**Edit**: If `msg_code` is a dotted string like `vote.dup`, then you will need to split it and walk the objects' properties one at a time. Here's a generic solution:

```
function walkPath( object, pathString ){
  var prop, names = pathString.split('.');
  while (object && (prop=names.shift())) object = object[prop];
  return object;
}
alert( walkPath( myapp.msg, msg_code ) );
```

Comment: seems to work with only one level i.e `myapp.msg.vote[msg_code]` where `msg_code` is `dupe`; doesn't work when `msg_code` is `vote.dupe`;

Comment: @james Sorry, I missed that requirement at first. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you. do you know if it adds overhead? will using of eval really bad here? the msg_code will be returned from the server side and considered secure.

Comment: @james It will be faster, better, and safer than `eval`. You won't notice any speed hit unless you are processing a path with something like 50,000 periods.

Answer (score 1):

ok now depending on how many different messages you have availabe, you can use a switch statement to select the correct message:

```
function alert_msg(msg_code) { 
   var msg='';
   switch(msg_code){
   case 0:
   // message 
   msg = myapp.msg.vote.dupe
   break;
   case 1 :
   msg = myapp.msg.vote.somethingelse
   ....
   }

   alert(msg); 
}
```

or like you said you can use eval, but not really recommended